# How to get the penultimate date differentiating the day but not taking into account the time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem; I want to get the penultimate date without taking into account the time. This is my query:

```
select max_date,
       (select max(t2.date) from table t2 where t2.date<t1.max_date)
from (select max(max_date) from table) as t1;
```

my data are:

```
2018-06-12 10:43:45.000,
2018-06-12 10:42:45.000,
2018-06-12 10:41:45.000,
2018-05-12 10:43:45.000,
```

I currently get:

```
2018-06-12 10:43:45.000,
2018-06-12 10:42:45.000,
```

but I want:

```
2018-06-12 10:43:45.000,
2018-05-12 10:43:45.000
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

This query will work on SQL Server:

```
SELECT max_date,
       (SELECT MAX(t2.date) 
        FROM test t2 
        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, t2.date) < CONVERT(DATE, t1.max_date)) AS penultimate_date
FROM (SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date 
      FROM test) t1
```

The only difference is the use of `CONVERT` to convert a `DATETIME` value to a `DATE`, rather than `DATE` which is a MySQL only function.

[Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb59774c4bd7e5821a6f902c254640e9)

**Original answer** (MySQL, as question was only tagged `sql` at the time)

The issue with your query is that you are comparing the date as a full timestamp, rather than just looking at the date portion. This is why you are getting the previous value from the same day, instead of the previous day. Change the query to this:

```
SELECT max_date,
       (SELECT MAX(t2.date) 
        FROM test t2 
        WHERE DATE(t2.date) < DATE(t1.max_date)) AS penultimate_date
FROM (SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date 
      FROM test) t1;
```

Output:

```
max_date            penultimate_date
2018-06-12 10:43:45 2018-05-12 10:43:45
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJZnDdo2kNxWSg4Lgbnedq/4)

Comment: @Luis you had only specified `sql` in your tags. I should have asked which DBMS. Anyway I've updated the answer with something that works on SQL Server.